# node ./server/index.mjs process unexpectedly started overloading CPU in Nuxt 3 app deployed on Ubuntu server with pm2

Tags: cpu-usage, pm2, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt 3 ssr app deployed on Ubuntu server with pm2 as per official documentation. One and a half month into production time the website became drammatically slow all of a sudden. `htop` showed that it was node `./server/index.mjs` that was taking up almost all the CPU capacity. I restarted pm2 and the productivity and speed restored to optimal. Now it worked fine for 5 days and the situation repeated. Stopping and starting pm2 saved the day but obviously I have to debug. Has anybody encountered something like this. Is it a memory leak or may it be something else?
Below is the pm2 ecosystem file and htop oveload state
[image]
[image]

Comment: How can we know what configs you have if you don't post them? Please add minimal code possible. May be pm2 config, nuxt.config etc.